# How to set correct time on Windows and Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, windows, time

I'm on Windows 10, with a VMWare guest Ubuntu.
Following commands show they have different time, Ubuntu is ahead by 1 second.

```
~$ ssh ubuntu date +%s;date +%s
1578128791
1578128790
```

Then I resynchronized Windows Internet Time with:

```
w32tm /resync
```

And Ubuntu with:

```
ntpdate -s ntp.ubuntu.com
```

But the times are still different.

How can I know which time is correct, or they are both wrong ?

Comment: Could it be [this](https://vmspot.com/vmware-leap-second/)?

Comment: @xenoid, on Windows, it should make the adjustment as well as I have synchronized.

Comment: 1. Are you running VMWare and the Guest in the mode where it automatically synchronises its time from the Host? 2. Are you running NTP or some other time service daemon on the Guest? 3. Are you aware that SNTP only claims an accuracy of about one second, so your two systems being one second apart is perfectly "acceptable"?

Comment: I did set the guest to synchronize with the host, but I didn't check "Update automatically", now the times seem in sync, thank you !

Comment: Did you wait to give time to finish the time adjustment?

Comment: Yes, after running the two commands in my post, I kept comparing time for about 30 seconds.